# Add and Remove Row Actions in an Existing WP_List_Table

Tags: wp-admin, actions, wp-list-table, row-actions

I would like to modify the row actions of an existing WP_List_Table. For example, in the Users section in the back end, I would like to remove the "Edit" option from each user.

I would like to also add new actions, such as "Books", which would list the books read by this user (this works with another plugin).

I have a feeling it is some sort of filter, but could not find anything in documentation.

Please note that I am not creating a new table. This is an existing WordPress table (e.g., Users).

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [`user_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_row_actions/) which is specifically for the `WP_Users_List_Table` class which extends `WP_List_Table`.

Comment: @SallyCJ - Thanks. Maybe you should add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done, @Greeso. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the user rows in the **Users list table** (at *wp-admin/users.php*), you would use the [`user_row_actions` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_row_actions/) like so:

```php
add_filter( 'user_row_actions', 'my_user_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function my_user_row_actions( $actions, $user_object ) {
    // Remove the Edit action.
    unset( $actions['edit'] );

    // Add your custom action.
    $actions['my_action'] = '<a href="<action URL>">Action</a>';

    return $actions;
}
```

The other WordPress list tables which extend the [`WP_List_Table` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/) also fire a similar hook with the same naming convention, i.e. `<text>_row_actions`, and here are the *other* available hooks list as of writing:

**Note:** These hooks mostly have only two parameters — `$actions` (an array of action links) and an object representing a post, term, user or comment — but the `media_row_actions` has a third parameter named `$detached` (see the docs for more details).

- [`page_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_row_actions/) — fires in the **Pages list table** (`page` post type); second param: `$post` (a `WP_Post` instance)
- [`post_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/) — fires in the **Posts list table** (`post` and custom post types); second param: `$post` (a `WP_Post` instance)

  Note that this hook and the one above, they are fired in the *same list table **class*** which is `WP_Posts_List_Table`.
- [`media_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_row_actions/) — fires in the **Media list table**; second param: `$post` (a `WP_Post` instance)
- [`comment_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_row_actions/) — fires in the **Comments list table** (which is also used in the *Recent Comments* dashboard widget); second param: `$comment` (a `WP_Comment` instance)
- [`ms_user_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/ms_user_row_actions/) — fires in the ***Network (or Multisite)* Admin Users list table**; second param: `$user` (a `WP_User` instance)
- [`<taxonomy>_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_row_actions/) — fires in the **Terms list table** ( for Tags (`post_tag`), Categories (`category`) and custom taxonomies ); second param: `$tag` (a `WP_Term` instance)
- [`tag_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tag_row_actions/) — same as above, i.e. for *any taxonomy* — but if you want to target a specific taxonomy, you might want to use the above hook instead